# std::basic_ofstream<std::uin8_t>. Is it supposed to be like this?

Tags: c++

```
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    std::basic_stringstream<std::uint8_t> stream;
    std::uint8_t buf[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, 10};

    stream.write(buf, sizeof(buf));

    std::basic_ofstream<std::uint8_t> file{"file", std::ios::binary};
    auto str = stream.str();
    file.write(str.data(), str.size());

    return 0;
}
```

Results are different for Windows (Visual Studio compiler) and g++/clang++. Is it supposed to be like this? And what is this actually? It's not like a huge problem since it can be hacked by just using `basic_ofstream<char>` and simple `reinterpret_cast`. Just want to know, though.

For me expected result is to have a file with name "file" near executable with binary data inside from buf[] array.

For VC++ I've got the right thing while g++/clang++ create an empty "file" without any data.

Making it

```
std::ofstream file{"file", std::ios::binary};
auto str = stream.str();
file.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(str.data()), str.size());
```

solves the problem. But what is happening there? I've seen some funny stuf in winapi but this is just incredible.

Comment: Are you sure the file is empty?  ascii 1-10 are non-printable characters.  If you open it in a hex editor is the data in there?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. The first thing I tried was to open IPython console and read file in binary mode. It returned nothing. + those 1,2,3,4,5 are random, it doesn't work in general (encountered this while trying to fix a bug at work).

Comment: what version of the compilers are you using?  What standard are you compiling against?

Comment: Have no idea how to extract actual version of VC++, but it's the one present in Visual Studio 2017 15.7.5.
g++ 8.2.1 (archlinux), cygwin(7.3.0)
clang++ 7.0.0

Tried all standards from g++ but non of them worked.

Comment: [This doesn't compile for me with clang + libc++](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/G6MgKG). I'm not sure who is in the right here, but this is certainly an interesting question.

Comment: This may be a buffering issue, try adding a stream.close() before you attempt re-opening the file.

Comment: Have you made sure that `char_traits<std::uint8_t>` is defined?

Comment: Seems like it's defined but not always. If it does not compile with clang++ libc. But I wonder why it works in VC++. And why it compiles with g++/clang++ without libc parameter.

For me it is expected to at least see a working <>::write(const T* ptr, std::size_t size) method. Since there is no need in any info about the underlying type. You just take objects and copy them into buffer (and then flush into file).

Comment: So, Did you figure what's happening here?